# Is the map $x\mapsto x^2+x$ uniformly continuous on $(0,\infty)$?

Tags: uniform-continuity, epsilon-delta

I want to find whether $x\mapsto x^2 + x$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,\infty)$, I know that $x\mapsto x^2$ is not uniformly continuous on this interval, however am having difficulty grasping whether this function is. This is what I have done so far I have made the function $$|x^2 +x -y^2 +x|<\varepsilon$$ where I made it $$|(x+y)(x-y)(1)|<\varepsilon.$$

Am I on the right track?

Comment: A relatively useful lemma you could prove would be that all uniformly continuous functions are bounded above by some $mx+b$.

Answer (score 2):

The sum of uniformly continuous functions is again an uniformly continuous function, and if you multiply the function by a scalar too. Note that the identity is uniformly continuous (it is Lipschitz). You know that $x^2$ is not uniformly continuous. If $x^2+x$ were uniformly continuous, we would have: $$x^2 = (x^2+x) - x$$ uniformly continuous, a contradiction. So $x^2+x$ is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: I am asked to solve it using epsilon delta however, is this possible??

Comment: You can use the same method to prove that $x^2$ is not uniformly continuous, it will work. Take $x = n+ \frac{1}{n}$ and $y = n$, $\epsilon = 1$, or something in these lines (for $n$ big enough we will have a problem in the definition of uniform continuity).

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x^2+x$ for $x\in(0,\infty)$. Take $\varepsilon=1$. Let $\delta>0$ be given. Choose $M$ such that $$M > \frac1\delta +\delta+\frac12 .$$ Then $\left|M - (M+\frac\delta2)\right|=\frac\delta2<\delta$, but 
\begin{align}\left|f(M) - f(M+\frac\delta2)\right| &= \left(M+\frac\delta2\right)^2 - (M+\frac\delta2) - (M^2 - M)\\
&= M^2 + M\delta + \frac{\delta^2}4 - M-\frac\delta 2 - M^2 + M\\
&= M\delta +\frac{\delta^2}4 - \frac\delta2\\
&> \left(\frac1\delta+\delta+\frac12\right)\delta + \frac{\delta^2}4-\frac\delta2\\
&= 1+\frac{5\delta^2}4 > 1.
\end{align}
Hence, $f$ is not uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1):

If $f'$ is monotonic increasing and unbounded on $(0,\infty)$, then the function $f$ cannot be uniformly continuous. This should be intuitively true, just looking at the graph, so let's prove it. Without loss of generality, $f'>0$. Pick any $\epsilon>0$ and suppose there exists a $\delta>0$ such that

$$|x-y|<\delta\,\Rightarrow\,|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon.$$

Then in particular $|f(x+\frac{1}{2}\delta)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x$, so it's bounded. But

$$\left|f\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\delta\right)-f(x)\right|=\int_x^{x+\delta/2}f'(u)\,{\rm d}u>\frac{1}{2}\delta\, f'(x)\to\infty,$$

and this is a contradiction!